# Magento product view template based on category

Tags: magento

We are working on a Magento webshop which has two categories.

We would like to use the default product view template for category one, and a custom product view template for category two.

Is this possible and how we can achieve this?

*** EDIT - SOLUTION ***

For anyone who is curious about this. The solution was a lot easier than I thought.

I only had to place this piece of code in the custom layout update section of the relevant category and i had to set the option 'Apply to products' to yes!

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate"> <template>catalog/product/view-recipe.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

*** EDIT ***
I have tried adding this code to the catalog.xml.

```
<CATEGORY_5>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view-recipe.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</CATEGORY_5>
```

*** EDIT ***
I have tried adding this code to the catalog.xml:

```
<CATEGORY_5>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view-recipe.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</CATEGORY_5>
```

And this code to the Custom Layout Update section:

```
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view-recipe.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

I installed the patch but unfortunately still no results.

Comment: Michael, If I am not mistaken, you should put `<CATEGORY_5>` block in layout update section. Did you try this as well?

Comment: I tried but without success. I have no idea what we're doing wrong.

Comment: Hi Oğuz. Please see edited start post for the solution!

Answer (score 5):

Did you mean category catalog list? Then you can try "Custom Layout Update".

- Catalog -> Manage Categories
- Select custom layout from "Page Layout"
- Add the following in "Custom Layout Update"

```
<reference name="product_list">
<action method="setTemplate">
    <template>catalog/product/custom-theme.phtml</template>
</action>
</reference>
```

Of course, you should create first `custom layout`, you can take reference from the base list.phtml

*** EDIT ***
If you want customize specific products/categories then you can use `custom layout handle`. Take consider the following links.

- [Advanced Layout Updates](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/advanced-layout-updates-for-categories-and-products-in-magento/)
- [Creating custom layout handles](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/creating-custom-layout-handles/)

*** EDIT ***
First you should modify `CategoryController.php` `viewAction()` method from `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Controllers` folder ( as specified in Inchoo sample ).

Then, you should do something like that :

```
<CATEGORY_20>
<reference name="product.info">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/custom-theme.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</CATEGORY_20>
```

*** EDIT ***
Magento has a bug about Custom Layout Update which is issue id 7625. They specified fixed in next release over Bug Track but still has a problem. So, `Ingo Weseloh` made a patch which you can find the following link.

[Exanto Reclayup](https://github.com/novalis111/Magento-Recursive-Layout-Updates)
7625

*** EDIT ***

Michael, could you please try this ( it's Alan Storm's sugestion )

```
<CATEGORY_20>
<reference name="product.info">
  <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/custom-theme.phtml</template></action>
  <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Hi Oğuz. No I don't mean the product list but the product view, as mentioned in the start post.

Comment: Hi Oğuz. I don't get it. The default catalog.xml refers to catalog/product/view.phtml within the <catalog_product_view> section. How I can make a custom layout handle which refers to /catalog/product/view-custom.phtml for for example category 5?

Comment: Michael, specifically look inchoo sample. You should modify base action ( adding layout handle ) then use in layout update xml section.

Comment: Hi Oğuz. Still not succeeded. I used your code above in the layout update xml section. Should I add the code somewhere else also?

Comment: yes, as I said in the comment, you should take care of inchoo sample. They modified `CategoryController` controllers `viewAction()` method.

Comment: Michael, did you modify `CategoryController.php`?

Comment: I think they have not modified the CategoryController.php. They only refer to it. I think my code is in the wrong place.

Comment: Sory Michael :(, you are right, they didn't modify the code which I checked right now.

Comment: I am afraid of that there was a bug about this feature which is issue id `7625`. Someones tried to fix but I can not acces his SVN right now. [Magento Hack](http://www.exanto.de/magento-module-und-hacks.html/comment-page-1#comment-118347) and [Custom Layout update fix](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/30570/)

Comment: Hi Oğuz. I really appreciate your effort. Please see my edited start post.